# How to generate elastic search nested aggregations in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, resthighlevelclient

I have the below aggregation query which i need to translate into java

Below aggregation query needs to be translated into java using elastic search client RestHighLevelCleint
not sure i tried multiple times but the java code is not able to translate as per the below query.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "recommendations": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "events.recommendationData"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "exception": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "events.recommendationData.exceptionId": [
                "2"
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "exceptionIds": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "events.recommendationData.exceptionId.keyword",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggs": {
                "recommendations": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "events.recommendationData.recommendations"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "recommendationType": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.recommendationType",
                        "size": 10
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

using the below code with RestHighLevelClient

```
AggregationBuilder recommendations =
                AggregationBuilders.nested("recommendations", "events.recommendationData");

        AggregationBuilder exception = AggregationBuilders
                    .filter("exception", QueryBuilders.termsQuery("events.recommendationData.exceptionId", "2"));

        AggregationBuilder exceptionIds = AggregationBuilders.terms("exceptionIds")
                .field("events.recommendationData.exceptionId.keyword").size(10);

        AggregationBuilder recommendations2 =
                AggregationBuilders.nested("recommendations", "events.recommendationData.recommendations");

        AggregationBuilder recommendationType = AggregationBuilders.terms("recommendationType")
                .field("events.recommendationData.recommendations.recommendationType").size(10);

        AggregationBuilder build = 
                recommendations
                        .subAggregation(exception)
                        .subAggregation(exceptionIds)
                        .subAggregation(recommendations2)
                        .subAggregation(recommendationType);
```

and it is producing the wrong query as i posted below which is not working.

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "recommendations": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "events.recommendationData"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "exception": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "events.recommendationData.exceptionId": [
                "1",
                "2"
              ],
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "exceptionIds": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "events.recommendationData.exceptionId.keyword",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
              {
                "_count": "desc"
              },
              {
                "_key": "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "recommendations": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events.recommendationData.recommendations"
          }
        },
        "recommendationType": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.recommendationType",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
              {
                "_count": "desc"
              },
              {
                "_key": "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected: Every aggregation is a sub aggregation to the previous.

Therefore, if you see the expected query, `recommendationType` is sub-aggregation of `recommendations2`. These together are sub-aggregation to `exceptionIds` and so on. Therefore only one line needs to change here, which is instead of

```
 AggregationBuilder build = 
                recommendations
                        .subAggregation(exception)
                        .subAggregation(exceptionIds)
                        .subAggregation(recommendations2)
                        .subAggregation(recommendationType);
```

use this,

```
recommendations.subAggregation(
        exception.subAggregation(
            exceptionIds.subAggregation(
                recommendations2.subAggregation(recommendationType)
            )
        )
    );
```